# Splitting two person conversation in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

sentence = """Speaker1: Hello. My name is GUS. I can help you plan a simple trip by air. Where do you want to go ?
Speaker2: I want to go to San Diego on May 28
Speaker1: What time do you want to leave?
Speaker2: I must be in San Diego before 10 am
Speaker1: Would you like P.S.A. flight 102 that arrives at 9.15 am ?
Speaker2: What is the next flight ?
Speaker1: Air California flight 310 that leaves at 8.30am and arrives at 10.00am
Speaker2: I’ll take the first one
Speaker1: In what name should I make a reservation, please?
Speaker2: Dan Bobrow
Speaker1: I have confirmed the following flight: P.S.A. flight 102 on Wednesday May 28
from San Jose to San Diego that leaves at 7.30 am and arrives at 9.15 am.
Speaker1: What date do you want to return on ?
Speaker2: On Friday in the evening.
Speaker1: Would you like the flight that leaves at 7.45 pm ?
Speaker2: That’s fine.
Speaker1: I have confirmed the following flight: P.S.A. flight 307 on Friday May 30 from
San Diego to San Jose that leaves at 7.45 pm and arrives at 9.30 pm Thank you
for calling. Goodbye"""

I need to split speaker1 and speaker2 conversation separately in python

Comment: when you say split, do you mean group??

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following (naive) strategy should be effective for your use case:

```
split_sentence = sentence.split(' ')
speaker_1_sentences = []
speaker_2_sentences = []
current_speaker_is_1 = True
current_sentence = []
for word in split_sentence:
    if word == 'Speaker1:':
        current_speaker_is_1 = True
        if len(current_sentence) > 0:
            speaker_1_sentences.append(' '.join(current_sentence))
            current_sentence = []
        continue
    elif word == 'Speaker2:':
        current_speaker_is_1 = False
        if len(current_sentence) > 0:
            speaker_2_sentences.append(' '.join(current_sentence))
            current_sentence = []
        continue
    current_sentence.append(word)
print(speaker_1_sentences)
print(speaker_2_sentences)
```

It involves iterating through the conversation and alternating between adding the sentences to the first and second speakers. You may way want to consider a regex based solution, depending on your requirements.

Comment: HI I need the output into two groups one containing all speaker1 conversation and another containing all speaker2 conversation for eg:-

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group them:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

dat = re.split(' (?=Speaker\\d+)', sentence)
key = lambda x: re.sub(':.*', '', x)
result = groupby(sorted(dat, key = key), key = key)

final = {i:list(j) for i,j in result}

print(final['Speaker1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break the dialog into clauses representing either speaker numbers or their words with `re.split` and then combine odd and even clauses into a list of tuples:

```
clauses = re.split(r'Speaker(\d+):\s+', sentence)
conversation = list(zip(clauses[1::2], clauses[2::2])
#[('1', 'Hello. My name is GUS...'), ...]
```

The list can be converted into a dictionary organized by speaker if needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict
conversation_dict = defaultdict(list)
for speaker, phrase in conversation:
    conversation_dict[speaker].append(phrase)
```